# How can I add directory with ascending name such as dir-000, dir-001 etc

Tags: bash

I want to copy a directory into another directory at various times. Each time, I want the new name to be one number higher than before / I want to be able to grab that number and store it into a variable.

So if I have a:

```
mymaindir

/home/user/dirs/STRING_000
/home/user/dirs/STRING_001
```

And I run my script, `mymaindir` would be copied to `/home/user/dirs/STRING_002` and I could get the value `2` from that. I've just been looking at different things like `split` but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk one liner can do that:

```
arr=( $(find . -name "STRING_*" | awk -F "_" '{if ($2>max) max=$2} 
        END{max++; printf("%d STRING_%03d\n", max, max)}') )

maxVal=${arr[0]}
fileName=${arr[1]}
```

Comment: I'm only being cheeky, but technically it's not a one-liner :)

Comment: @dreamlax: Its indeed awk one liner, I just inserted new line in order to display it correctly without scrollbar :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use some form of this:

```
highest=$(find -name 'string_[0-9]*' | cut -d_ -f2 | sort -nr | head -1)
newname="string_$(printf "%03d" "$(( $highest+ 1))")"
```